# Regular expression match in javascript on a list of items

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check in javascript if my string contains any of the characters `~` and `’`.

Is there a way to achieve this using regular expression match test, rather than writing a for loop to check if my string contains any of there characters using indexOf()

Comment: You don't need indexOf, just Regex.test() will work for you

Comment: Just an idea, but perhaps you could look for "regular expression" in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: Use includes if you want, it will return true or false , var t = '234234~1'' console.log(t.includes('~')) // true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`regex.test(str);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is the thing you want to check. It looks in `str` if it is mathing `regex`, `true` if it does, else `false`

```js
var a = "hey";
var b = "h~y";
var c = "he’";
var reg = /[’~]/ ;
console.log(reg.test(a)); // false
console.log(reg.test(b)); // true
console.log(reg.test(c)) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to find given string using `indexOf()` it will return value greater than -1. If value is 0,1 or any number then `true` else `false`.

```js
var string = "Some Text'";
if (string.indexOf("~") > -1 || string.indexOf("'") > -1)
{
  console.log("contains");
}else{
  console.log("not contains");
}
```